# Using induction for a specific set of natural numbers

Tags: soft-question, induction

I'm trying to understand how to use induction to prove a claim not for every natural number $n$, but only for specific natural numbers, say $0 \leq n \leq k$ for some positive $k$.

After proving $P(0)$, does it make sense to assume the proposition is true for $P(n)$ when $0 \leq n \leq k - 1$? In this way, I won't have to consider $n = k + 1$, and I believe the proof follows for all such $n$.

Comment: Yes, you can use [strong induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208095/ordinary-induction-vs-strong-induction-on-the-same-example?rq=1), but you need to show the induction step nevertheless, namely $P(k)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the property $Q$ be defined as $Q(n)=P(n)$ for $n\leq k$ and $Q(n)=\text{true}$ for $n> k$. Then showing that $Q$ is true for all $n$ is equivalent to show that $P(n)$ is true for all $n\leq k$. Now proving $Q(n)$ to be true for all $n$ by induction obviously means that

1. $P(0)$ has to be true and
2. P(n+1) is true provided that $P(n)$ is true for all $ n\leq k-1$.

So this justifies your idea of proof.